# Adding Powershell Script to C# project

Tags: c#, powershell

So I'm fairly new to programming so hoping someone can help me out here. I'm building a C# application that requires a powershell script, now whilst I know how to call the script using Runspaces and Pipeline, this method requires referencing the scripts location within the code, which will pose a problem if this application is to be used by someone else besides myself. Does anybody know if there is a way to add a powershell script to a project so it can be referenced instead of me having to reference a file location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a two things that come to mind:

1. Inline your Powershell script in C# (Use StringBuilder to build your powershell script).
2. Embed your powershell script as a text resource and read it as a stream, execute it. Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file).